# Why do i need QML when i have C++ in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have been working in Qt for nearly 4 - 5 month and now i found QML. First i thought that QML is front-end of your project while c++ is back-end. And if it is really so why the hack i learned QWidgets, QTreeView, QTableWidget...etc if i don`t use them in my project as QML comes here!!! I feel very "annoyance". What i mean that why Qt created QML as it has above widgets and C++ (the best language for me:)? In some QML books i found that it is completaly a language which has everything in c++, i mean network, class, function so on... and which one should i use when working in Qt c++ or QML?

Comment: You can work with anyone, with whom you feel more comfortable, your question is based on opinions and it seems that you have not done any serious research. QML is a declarative language that I believe Qt. You can use one of them or you can use both together.

Comment: C++ and QML serve different purposes and different audiences but also interoperate quite well. So use whatever you need; one or the other or both.  Mix and match as you please.

Comment: Is existing of QML disturbing you? I've worked in Qt for ~10 years and still don't know anything about QML. Nobody is making you to use it.

Comment: I may be wrong and it is a little bit out of topic but if you want a good working cooperation example between a "descriptive Xml" and a "imperative" language have a look to Xaml and C# (with data binding in mvvm methodology for example). imho I do not know any equivalent in C++ and I should say it is a pity especially when building simple(?) GUI

Comment: QML allows UI interfaces to be **described** - declarative . Yes it is _JUST_ a _Front End_,  mainly for _mobile_ applications. QWidgets are not designed for mobile apps .. while it just works, most widgets are almost useless in mobile apps where you need flexibility of lightweight components incorporating JS/Json .. you never design a backend _heavy_ application with QML, you do it with Qt c++ .. almost independently on any UI, while QtQuick is centric to qml

Comment: Well, widget forms are declarative too, it is just that the language is XML-like rather than JSON-like.

Comment: @dtech, true, but you never call that xml-like: a _code_ as its auto created from designer, while QML (java script like) code is accessible either. my primary intention was to highlight what others didn't mention, namely: mobile apps.

Comment: QML also has a form generator / graphical designer. I know people who have been writing widget forms too ;) To each his own. And it is XML-like, in fact it is generic XML...

Comment: @dtech rather it's looks like json + js, not xml.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov we are talking about widget forms, not qml.

Comment: @dtech yeah, it was my misunderstood. Thought that you are talking about qml :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, with C++ you can only use the old QtWidgets API GUI-wise. That's pretty much a done deal, aside from bug fixes it is no longer actively developed. All GUI stuff since Qt 5.0 relies on the QML language.

QML is very good for rapid prototyping, and is overall much faster to develop in. It has stuff like dynamic scoping and property bindings which make certain tasks trivial, whereas implementing them in C++ is actually quite tedious, and not always possible. Bugs usually cause error messages rather than crashes and are much easier to catch than in C++, and it really helps to iron things out when you don't have to wait for recompilation on every little change. It also employs JS, where you can use the extra level of dynamism to get even more development speed up. Last but not least, it is really quick and easy to make "cool GUI" with it, another thing that's rather tedious to do in C++.

Its advantages unfortunately and understandably come with shortcomings too. Performance is much lower, so it is not suitable for critical tasks, it is a memory hog, there are certain limitations due to the reliance on high level abstractions you don't have control over, although granted this sort of stuff happens when using the C++ APIs, in many cases you can extend and override some aspects of the behavior to an extent. The GUI types are less mature and there are still some things missing. Last but not least, you are cut off from most of the Qt libraries, if you want to utilize the existing C++ functionality you have to interface it manually.

You don't have to use QML if you don't want to. Unless your boss makes you or something like that. You can definitely do more in C++, although it is harder and slower to do. The two API layers are not in competition, they are complimentary. QML is much easier to learn as well, although some of the design paradigms it enables tend to feel alien to C++ developers initially. But once you get it, it becomes a valuable tool in the skill set. I myself enjoy a 5-10x boost in productivity from using QML.